# BASH SCRIPT -> ssh server_name sudo -u user sqlplus query -> into variable

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

in my script part I need to:

1. SSH to other server
2. Using sudo -u run sqlplus (company policy -> no other way, no possibility to change the Linux parameters.)
3. Save output to the variable for later use withing the script

It does work for me without variable.
I am trying following approach (unfortunately does not work with variable):

```
TEST_VARIABLE=$(`ssh -q -S $1 sudo -u dbabatch /some_path/dba/sqlplus $SOURCE_INSTANCE << EOF
select * from v$instance;
exit`
EOF)
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Your EOF is contained within the backtick, so this looks like a syntax error. Also using dollar expression is redundant with backticks

Comment: better to just drop the bacticks and rely on modern command substitution with `var=$(... cmds ...)` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed backticks but it stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
TEST_VARIABLE=$(ssh -q -S $1 sudo -u dbabatch /some_path/dba/sqlplus -s $SOURCE_INSTANCE <<EOF
SET HEADING OFF NEWPAGE NONE TRIMSPOOL ON
select * from v\$instance;
EOF
)
```

`SET HEADING OFF NEWPAGE NONE TRIMSPOOL ON` suppresses column header and page brakes (actually not needed if you get only one row back)

`sqlplus -s` suppresses the sqlplus banner and sqlplus prompt.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Unfortunately I am getting: "unknown option -- u" using this.

Comment: TEST_VARIABLE=$(ssh -q -S $1 sudo -u dbabatch /some_path/dba/sqlplus -s $SOURCE_INSTANCE << EOF
SET HEADING OFF NEWPAGE NONE TRIMSPOOL ON
select * from v\$instance;
EOF)

Comment: I think it is difficult to combine command substitution + sudo + ssh + here documents. Maybe put `/some_path/dba/sqlplus -s $SOURCE_INSTANCE <<EOF
SET HEADING OFF NEWPAGE NONE TRIMSPOOL ON
select * from v\$instance;
EOF
) ` into a shell script at other server and simply execute this script.

Comment: Yes this is the backup way. I just wanted to avoid that solution because of heavy usage of the script and in case of troubles with the script the temperary files may not be deleted.